# Google Maps `gmnoprint` marker elements with opacity set

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I was looking into performance issues with my map and I realized that all my markers are wrapped in a `gmnoprint` which is normal but some have opacity set:

```
<div class="gmnoprint" style="opacity: 0.01; width: 12px; height: 19.992px; overflow: hidden; position: absolute; cursor: pointer; left: 962px; top: 295px; z-index: 6422;"><img src="...</div>
```

When I set this CSS it helps some but **I'm curious why this is even happening**

```
.gmnoprint {
  opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

UPDATE: I noticed one other weird thing. When I set the marker `optimized` to `false` the opacity is there. When I set optimized `true` opacity is no longer there.

UPDATE 2: Not sure why this is marked as "unlcear what I'm asking". I've bolded the question to hopefully make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to set the markers opacity by passing the option when you create them:

```
new google.maps.Marker({
  map: map,
  position: latlng,
  opacity: 1
})
```

Or you can also change it after creation like this:

```
marker.setOpacity(1);
```

Setting it as a css property seems like a less than optimal solution.

Comment: Yea if you see the bold text im not setting that at all. Something is setting the markers to that opacity. the markers do have that but it's changing the opacity when changing the optimized param